How does the function know the <li> element to be chosen?
I was writing an exercise for the active learning portion of this tutorial on mdn, it's very guided so the coding was easy, the code will be included now:
        const list = document.querySelector("ul");
        const input = document.querySelector("#item");
        const btn = document.querySelector("button");

        let inputText;

        btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            inputText = input.value;
            input.value = "";
            const li = document.createElement("li");
            const span = document.createElement("span");
            const btnElement = document.createElement("button");
            list.appendChild(li);
            li.appendChild(span);
            li.appendChild(btnElement);
            span.textContent = inputText;
            btnElement.textContent = "Delete";
            btnElement.addEventListener("click", () => li.remove());
            input.focus();
        });

This code creates a shopping list, as described in the image that you can see below
Output of the code, source from mdn web docs where the tutorial is shared
The functionality of the code is basic, you type an item on the input element and the item will get added to the  list together with a button that has "Delete" as its text content.
Now I can ask the question, while coding this I had the idea that this wouldn't work, I could not see how the program would identify the <li> I was referencing. I'll explain myself, how is it possible that when you delete let's say the humous element of the image it doesn't delete the bread element? After all, they were declared as const li = document.createElement("li");, so how does the program know that it has to delete its element? Is it because the button is inside of the <li> element? If we embedded it inside another element would that button remove the <li> element where it would be now inside?

Because li is a block-scoped variable inside the function
        btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            inputText = input.value;
            input.value = "";
            const li = document.createElement("li");
            const span = document.createElement("span");
            const btnElement = document.createElement("button");
            list.appendChild(li);
            li.appendChild(span);
            li.appendChild(btnElement);
            span.textContent = inputText;
            btnElement.textContent = "Delete";
            btnElement.addEventListener("click", () => li.remove());
            input.focus();
        });

and the block is inside the function's curly braces: {}
Whenever the function is called, all the variables inside the function (constants as well) are created as if nothing happened and with the line of
btnElement.addEventListener("click", () => li.remove());

it's basically referring to the li just created above. Whenever the click event is triggered, the btn event is called and a li constant is being created, which differs from all other li constants that were created by earlier function calls.
So, it's important to understand that the const you created inside the function does not live outside the function and is not being persisted across separate function calls. It is assigned for the btnElement click handler and each button element will be aware of what the corresponding li is.
